# Magento 2 Add Time to Special Price Date Start and Special Price Date End

Tags: magento2, special-price, calendar

In the calendar special price date start and special price date end, they using format date only like below image :

[image]

how can I modify this to add time on the calendar, I've checking Magento catalog module to find out the form but still cannot find it.